Shared extended properties on calendar event for which I am a guest and guestCanModify is enabled
I would like to set shared extended properties on a calendar event for which I am a guest and guestCanModify is enabled.
So far I have only been able to do so if I am also subscribed to the organizer's calendar.
Is there a way to patch the calendar event with new shared properties even if I am not subscribed to the organizer's calendar?
When trying to patch an event as a guest with guestCanModify = true and I am not subscribed to that calendar, I get a 403 error.
I used as the calendarId my guestId as well as the organizersId, but as mentioned this only works when I use the organizersId and only if I am subscribed.
Can I somehow use the CalUID to directly patch the calenderEvent ressource without going through the organizers calendar?
Any help is much appreciated!
